# Avoid hyperlinked TOC if hyperref is used

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm using the `hyperref` package because I have a link in my document, but do not want to have the TOC as links. How can this be done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I took the liberty to rephrase your title in order to reflect the actual question. I also changed the body because of this. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: If you only want to typeset an URL without making it a real hyperlink all you need is the `url` package which gives you `\url`.

Comment: Thank you, can I add the words instead of the link showing up like you would in the \href{linkto go to}{this is the text}

Comment: No, `\url` is just for URLs, not for hyperlinks. I'm afraid you need `hyperref` for links like this. I checked the manual but couldn't find an option to disable TOC links.

Comment: you could use something like `\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}` immediately before your `toc` and then change it immediately afterwards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Hyperref` has a somewhat under-documented switch for this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@none
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{aaa}
aaa
\section{bbb}
bbb
\end{document}
```

Comment: A "somewhat under-documented switch": this must be the understatement of the year! :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is the option `linktocpage` for hyperref; it defaults to 'false', while:

```
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
```

will make the page numbers rather than the text of the ToC the active link.  This, along with the suggestion of @cmhughes will minimize how 'clickable' your ToC is and even make it look like there are no links to click on.

Answer (score 5):

Modern versions of [`hyperref`](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) also have the `linktoc` option which supports `section`, `page`, `both`, or `none`. If you want to remove all links then `none` is the option you want.

```
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
```