# Contents, List of Figures: hyperref on the page number

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid hyperlinked TOC if hyperref is used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55190/avoid-hyperlinked-toc-if-hyperref-is-used)

In the process of finalizing a book I observed that it would be much better if I could translate the hyperref from the, e.g., Chapter name (left) to the page of the chapter (right). This means that I would rather like to make the page numbers to be colored in red, and to link to exactly that particular page number in the book, while the chapter name should remain in black color, and without any links associated with it. This should translate to List of Figures... How could this be achieved?

Comment: There's a package option `linktocpage`, see @jon's answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55190/avoid-hyperlinked-toc-if-hyperref-is-used).

Comment: @dgs After setting     \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black,hyperindex=true,pagebackref,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}    I get option clash for package hyperref. How could this be resolved?

Comment: Don't load the `hyperref` package twice with a `\usepackage` command. Either include the `linktocpage=true` declaration directly in the first `\usepackage` statement, or place it in the argument of a `\hypersetup` instruction.

Comment: ... of which the latter way allows you to make local changes, since in contrast to `\usepackage`, `\hypersetup` can be placed anywhere in the document. This would usually rather make sense e.g. for link colors, though.